# Java temperature converter using finals

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I get an exercise to write a temperature converter that must contain final variables.

As you will see, I'm using formulas to calculate the conversion between F,C and K. These formulas are final and they include "degree" variable, for example - `final double F_TO_C = Math.round((5/9.0)*(degree - 32) * 100.0) / 100.0;`

degree variable will taken from user input. My question is if there any way that I can use this final formula without using the degree variable because my teacher don't allow to use final that include variable.

Here is the program -

```
    /* This program is a temperature converter, based on user input (scale and degree), 
it converts to Celcius, Farenheit and Kelvin. */

import java.util.Scanner;
public class test

{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {

        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        char tempSymbol;
        double degree;

        System.out.println("Please enter a scale: ");
        String scale = scan.next();
        tempSymbol = scale.charAt(0); // Get the first char to know the scale (c/k/f)   

        System.out.println("Please enter the degree"); // Get the degree from user
        degree = scan.nextInt();

        // declaring converting formulas as finals and rounding them 
        final double F_TO_C = Math.round((5/9.0)*(degree - 32) * 100.0) / 100.0; 
        final double F_TO_K = Math.round((degree + 459.67) / 1.8 * 100.0) / 100.0;
        final double C_TO_F = Math.round(((9/5.0) * degree + 32) * 100.0) / 100.0;
        final double C_TO_K = Math.round((degree + 273.15) * 100.0) / 100.0;
        final double K_TO_F = Math.round(((9/5.0) * (degree - 273.15) + 32) * 100.0) / 100.0;
        final double K_TO_C = Math.round((degree - 273) * 100.0) / 100.0;

        switch (tempSymbol) { 
            case 'F': 
            case 'f': System.out.println("C " + F_TO_C);
                      System.out.println("F " + degree);
                      System.out.println("K " + F_TO_K);
                      break;
            case 'C':
            case 'c': System.out.println("C " + degree);
                      System.out.println("F " + C_TO_F);
                      System.out.println("K " + C_TO_K);  
                      break;
            case 'K': 
            case 'k': System.out.println("C " + K_TO_C);
                      System.out.println("F " + K_TO_F);
                      System.out.println("K " + degree);
                      break;
            default: System.out.println("No such temperature");
                     break;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: "I trying to use finals with other variable into it but it doesn't acceptable in my course." - Not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: My mean is that I cant do that according to my course instruction.

Comment: Well! we can all read minds.

Comment: I just did it, hope it will more clear now.

Comment: A formula is always expressed as method or function in programming, Variable can act as constants which your formula depends. So in your case I will say no.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare everything as `final` that is not reassigned. For example you can do this:

```
//declaring constants
final static Char F = 'F'
final static Char C = 'C'
final static Char K = 'K'

public static void main (String[]args)
{

    final Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a scale: ");
    final String scale = scan.next();
    final char tempSymbol = scale.charAt(0); // Get the first char to know the scale (c/k/f)   

    System.out.println("Please enter the degree"); // Get the degree from user
    final double degree = scan.nextInt(); //you should think about actually allowing a double here -> nextDouble()

 ...

    switch (Character.toUpperCase(tempSymbol)) { 
        case F:  System.out.println(C + " " + F_TO_C(degree));
                 System.out.println(F + " " + degree);
                 System.out.println(K + " " + F_TO_K);
                 break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally you can also declare a final function with a final parameter like this (I added static for good measure, makes sense for a conversion formula):

```
final static double F_TO_C(final double degrees){
    //consider decaring all constants i.e. 5, 9.0, 32 and 100 like F,C and K
    return Math.round((5/9.0)*(degrees - 32) * 100.0) / 100.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my mean was how can I use finals in the part of the formulas without the variable "degree".

Comment: You can only use `final` when you declare a class, method or variable, since you do neither of those you cant. The only thing you can do is to extract the constants `"C "`, `"F "` and `"K "`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Added a third way to enter a `final`keyword. 
Sidenote: With all that focus on final you might consider using a language like Kotlin, that has the nice `val` and `var` keywords.

Answer (score 0):

The formulae themselves can't really be final, as they are not "values". I think you misunderstood the requirements. Your requirement might just be to do something like leoderprofi did in their answer.

However, Java indeed has the capability to make "functions" variables, with the functional interfaces. Assuming that you did not misunderstand the requirements, this is what you need:

```
// These are DoubleUnaryOperators that "stores" how to convert from one scale to another
final DoubleUnaryOperator F_TO_C = d -> Math.round((5/9.0)*(d - 32) * 100.0) / 100.0;
final DoubleUnaryOperator F_TO_K = d -> Math.round((d + 459.67) / 1.8 * 100.0) / 100.0;
final DoubleUnaryOperator C_TO_F = d -> Math.round(((9/5.0) * d + 32) * 100.0) / 100.0;
final DoubleUnaryOperator C_TO_K = d -> Math.round((d + 273.15) * 100.0) / 100.0;
final DoubleUnaryOperator K_TO_F = d -> Math.round(((9/5.0) * (d - 273.15) + 32) * 100.0) / 100.0;
final DoubleUnaryOperator K_TO_C = d -> Math.round((d - 273) * 100.0) / 100.0;

switch (tempSymbol) {
    case 'F':
    case 'f': 
        // Here you pass "degree" into the function to calculate the temperature in the corresponding scale.
        System.out.println("C " + F_TO_C.applyAsDouble(degree));
        System.out.println("F " + degree);
        System.out.println("K " + F_TO_K.applyAsDouble(degree));
        break;
    case 'C':
    case 'c': System.out.println("C " + degree);
        System.out.println("F " + C_TO_F.applyAsDouble(degree));
        System.out.println("K " + C_TO_K.applyAsDouble(degree));
        break;
    case 'K':
    case 'k': System.out.println("C " + K_TO_C.applyAsDouble(degree));
        System.out.println("F " + K_TO_F.applyAsDouble(degree));
        System.out.println("K " + degree);
        break;
    default: System.out.println("No such temperature");
        break;
}
```